# button not working + button not reseting - roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a script where is someone presses a button a random event happens, to prevent the button being pressed multiple times, i added a Boolean value to the clickdetecter called "Clickable". but two proplems come with this, firstly sometimes nothing happens when you click the button it just turns red and unclickable, secondly for the second event the players get teleported but the button doesn't turn green and clickable

here is the script for the button itsself:

```
local Cat = script.Parent

Cat.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if Cat.ClickDetector.Clickable.Value == true then
        Cat.Color = Color3.fromRGB(255,0,0)
        Cat.ClickDetector.Clickable.Value = false
        
    end
end)
```

Here is the events script:

```
--variables
local Rep_storage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Cat = workspace["Cat button"].cat
local num_of_events = 2 --change depending on number of events
local Startergui = game:GetService("StarterGui")


--main function
Cat.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
    if Cat.ClickDetector.Clickable.Value == true then
        local Rand_event = math.random(1,num_of_events)
        --events
        if Rand_event == 1 then
            print ("ev 1")
            local zombie = Rep_storage["event items"]["Zombie"]
            local clone = zombie:Clone()
            clone.Archivable = true
            clone.Parent = workspace
            wait (30)
            clone:Destroy()
            Cat.Color = Color3.fromRGB(0,255,0)
            Cat.ClickDetector.Clickable.Value = true
        elseif Rand_event == 2 then 
            print ("ev 2")
            for _, plr in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren()) do
                plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = workspace["sky cat"].Part.CFrame
            Cat.Color = Color3.fromRGB(0,255,0)
            Cat.ClickDetector.Clickable.Value = true    
           end      
    
            
        end
    end
end)
```